# Can the Demon Hunter's Chakram hit enemies multiple times?

Tags: diablo-iii, diablo-iii-demon-hunter

The Demon Hunter's Chakram flies in a pattern out from her in a wide area of effect, but it circles around a bit and crosses its own path several times.

Is it possible for a single Chakram to inflict its damage multiple times to the same enemy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>Yes, it is indeed possible.</strike>

<strike>Take a look at [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=64645T7EloY#t=905s). The Demon Hunter's Chakram clearly hits the Skeletal Archer twice, before obliterating it.</strike>

Look like I was mistaken. Upon [further investigation](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cP_gqCQVJ0E#t=36s) of the Leoric (he has a fairly large hitbox) fight, it looks like the Chakram only hits once per target.

Comment: If you watch this video closely the Chakram only damages the skeleton once. The other damage that pops up is an Entangling Shot from the Demon Hunter.

Comment: @Krazer +StrixVaria is right. the damage 9 that pops up is from the arrow not from Chakram.

Answer (score -2):

I was not sure about the answer, though I did play the Demon Hunter.  Went on Diablo III forum and found this.

https://us.battle.net/d3/en/forum/topic/4247424868

According to this post, not only can it hit an enemy more then once, but that makes it one of the best DPS the game at the moment.

But yes, it's not that easy to land!

Comment: Can you expand a bit about what's said on the forum? It might move from that link then this answer wouldn't help much!

Comment: @amongrain , in the link you provide, the only post that mentioned multiple targets was [this one](https://us.battle.net/d3/en/forum/topic/4247424868?page=1#17) and he is asking the same question about multiple targets, He also comment that in **Diablo 2** The **Assassin** had a similar skill and **that similar skill** could hit multiple targets. This is why I'm down-voting your answer, If I'm mistaken, could you, please, provide more information about it (get the text from the link and past it in your answer with the appropriate link)

Comment: unfortunately it can't hit multiple times, tested this yesterday